# Connect iOS app with Apache Server using SSL certificate?

Tags: ios, apache, ssl, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking 2.0, and I have enabled certificate authentication on the Apache server. 
I have placed a .crt file in the xcode project.
and whenever I try to establish a https connection to the server I get the following error:

```
The operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)
```

Here is the code for calling the server :

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager setSecurityPolicy:[AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate]];
[manager POST:@"https://www.example.com/" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //success
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //failure
}];
```

Comment: What kind of certificate is it?

Comment: it's a self signed SSL certificate

Comment: That's your issue. iOS is extremely picky with certificate authentication. You need a fully legit certificate from a CA (you can get one for a free trial).

Comment: you can get a completely free one at StartSSL.com. Generally you shouldn't even need the crt file in the Xcode project as long as you've correctly installed you cert serverside.

Answer (score 0):

By default AFNetworking only pins against `.cer` files.

Rename your certificate so that it is `.cer` rather than `.crt` and it should work.

You can see if it's working by looking at the pinned certificates:

```
NSLog(@"Using %d pinned certificates", [manager.securityPolicy.pinnedCertificates count]);
```